# Unable to do web scraping from URL using Python Alchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a script where I'm trying to web scraping  the data into table. But  I'm getting errors

```
  raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
ValueError: No tables found
```

Script  :

```
import pandas as pd
import logging
from sqlalchemy import create engine
from urlib.parse import quote

db_connection = {mysql}://{username}:{quote'pwd'}@{DB:port}
ds_connection = create_engine(db_connection)
a = pd.read_html("https://www.centralbank.ae/en/forex-eibor/exchange-rates/")
df = pd.Dataframe(a[0])
df_final = df.loc[:,['Currency','Rate']]
df_final.to_sql('rate_table',db_connection,if_exists = append,index=false)
```

Can anyone suggest on this

Comment: There are no tables in the source of the page at that link. The table you seem to want to pursue seems to be added to the DOM using JavaScript, which `pd.read_html` is not capable of evaluating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to obtain those exchange rates would be to scrape the API accessed to retrieve information in page (check Dev Tools - network tab):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
          'Referer': 'https://www.centralbank.ae/en/forex-eibor/exchange-rates/'

          }
r = requests.post('https://www.centralbank.ae/umbraco/Surface/Exchange/GetExchangeRateAllCurrency', headers=headers)
dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
print(dfs[0].loc[:,['Currency','Rates']])
```

This returns:

|  | Currency | Rates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | US Dollar | 3.6725 |
| 1 | Argentine Peso | 0.026993 |
| 2 | Australian Dollar | 2.52753 |
| 3 | Bangladesh Taka | 0.038508 |
| 4 | Bahrani Dinar | 9.74293 |
| 5 | Brunei Dollar | 2.64095 |
| 6 | Brazilian Real | 0.706549 |
| 7 | Botswana Pula | 0.287552 |
| 8 | Belarus Rouble | 1.45526 |
| 9 | Canadian Dollar | 2.82565 |
| 10 | Swiss Franc | 3.83311 |
| 11 | Chilean Peso | 0.003884 |
| 12 | Chinese Yuan - Offshore | 0.536978 |
| 13 | Chinese Yuan | 0.538829 |
| 14 | Colombian Peso | 0.000832 |
| 15 | Czech Koruna | 0.149763 |
| 16 | Danish Krone | 0.496304 |
| 17 | Algerian Dinar | 0.025944 |
| 18 | Egypt Pound | 0.191775 |
| 19 | Euro | 3.69096 |
| 20 | GB Pound | 4.34256 |
| 21 | Hongkong Dollar | 0.468079 |
| 22 | Hungarian Forint | 0.009112 |
| 23 | Indonesia Rupiah | 0.000248 |
| 24 | Indian Rupee | 0.045976 |
| 25 | Iceland Krona | 0.026232 |
| 26 | Jordan Dinar | 5.17472 |
| 27 | Japanese Yen | 0.026818 |
| 28 | Kenya Shilling | 0.030681 |
| 29 | Korean Won | 0.002746 |
| 30 | Kuwaiti Dinar | 11.9423 |
| 31 | Kazakhstan Tenge | 0.007704 |
| 32 | Lebanon Pound | 0.002418 |
| 33 | Sri Lanka Rupee | 0.010201 |
| 34 | Moroccan Dirham | 0.353346 |
| 35 | Macedonia Denar | 0.059901 |
| 36 | Mexican Peso | 0.181874 |
| 37 | Malaysia Ringgit | 0.820395 |
| 38 | Nigerian Naira | 0.008737 |
| 39 | Norwegian Krone | 0.37486 |
| 40 | NewZealand Dollar | 2.27287 |
| 41 | Omani Rial | 9.53921 |
| 42 | Peru Sol | 0.952659 |
| 43 | Philippine Piso | 0.065562 |
| 44 | Pakistan Rupee | 0.017077 |
| 45 | Polish Zloty | 0.777446 |
| 46 | Qatari Riyal | 1.00254 |
| 47 | Serbian Dinar | 0.031445 |
| 48 | Russia Rouble | 0.06178 |
| 49 | Saudi Riyal | 0.977847 |
| 50 | Sudanese Pound | 0.006479 |
| 51 | Swedish Krona | 0.347245 |
| 52 | Singapore Dollar | 2.64038 |
| 53 | Thai Baht | 0.102612 |
| 54 | Tunisian Dinar | 1.1505 |
| 55 | Turkish Lira | 0.20272 |
| 56 | Trin Tob Dollar | 0.541411 |
| 57 | Taiwan Dollar | 0.121961 |
| 58 | Tanzania Shilling | 0.001575 |
| 59 | Uganda Shilling | 0.000959 |
| 60 | Vietnam Dong | 0.000157 |
| 61 | Yemen Rial | 0.01468 |
| 62 | South Africa Rand | 0.216405 |
| 63 | Zambian Kwacha | 0.227752 |
| 64 | Azerbaijan manat | 2.16157 |
| 65 | Bulgarian lev | 1.8873 |
| 66 | Croatian kuna | 0.491344 |
| 67 | Ethiopian birr | 0.069656 |
| 68 | Iraqi dinar | 0.002516 |
| 69 | Israeli new shekel | 1.12309 |
| 70 | Libyan dinar | 0.752115 |
| 71 | Mauritian rupee | 0.079837 |
| 72 | Romanian leu | 0.755612 |
| 73 | Syrian pound | 0.001462 |
| 74 | Turkmen manat | 1.05079 |
| 75 | Uzbekistani som | 0.000336 |

Comment: I will verify  with you code  and let  you know

Comment: I'm trying to change  Rates  column to Rate  but  it is  giving  me  key error  : [Rate] not  in index

Comment: @mohan111 I'm not sure what you're doing,  but my code works: I test my answers before posting them. If you need help renaming a pandas column, say so and I will update my answer.